# How do I arrange a list that includes a string and integer in vb.net?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

Okay, so I have a list of Highscores for my program which is kept in a text file, but I need to arrange them in ascending order.

**Here's the coding that I've got so far for it:**

```
WinnerName = txtName.Text
If Player1Wins = True Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("directory to my textfile, which I prefer not to disclose", _
    vbNewLine & WinnerName & "...................Total Moves made: " & PlayerOneRolls, True)
    txtList.Text = txtList.Text & vbNewLine & WinnerName & "...................Total Moves made: " & PlayerOneRolls
End If
If Player2Wins = True Then
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText("Directory to my text file, which I prefer not to disclose", _
    vbNewLine & WinnerName & "...................Total Moves made: " & PlayerTwoRolls, True)
    txtList.Text = txtList.Text & vbNewLine & WinnerName & "...................Total Moves made: " & PlayerTwoRolls
End If
```

**And here is what my text file looks like at the moment:**

> Clyde...................Total Moves made: 32
>   Above Law...................Total Moves made: 19
>   Billy Bob...................Total Moves made: 19
>   Pythagoras...................Total Moves made: 50
>   Peter Pan...................Total Moves made: 29

**This is what I want it to look like:**

> Above Law...................Total Moves made: 19
>   Billy Bob...................Total Moves made: 19
>   Peter Pan...................Total Moves made: 29
>   Clyde...................Total Moves made: 32
>   Pythagoras...................Total Moves made: 50

Comment: What criterion are you using for the sorting you want?

Comment: Are you firm on using the txt file? For the intermediate storage, I would recommend something like an XML. Then you can easily order by anything in code, and get your results the way you want.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in line with your text file based approach, basically read each line of the file into a list (accommodate for title row in file or other formatting I don't know about etc.). Then order the list by the score.

You can get the score by splitting the string on something you know should be there (":", you know what it is because you put it there; my suggestion is to use a variable to hold this string so the writer and reader use the same string...) then parsing the score component into an Integer - you may want to change this data type depending on score range etc. Use a Lambda to extract the score from each string to tell `OrderBy` how to sort.

Using ":" to split might be hazardous if someone has a ":" in their name. Open to suggestions.

```vb
Dim splitString As String = ":"
Dim scores As New List(Of String)
Using sr As New StreamReader("C:\scores.txt")
    While sr.Peek() > 0
        scores.Add(sr.ReadLine())
    End While
End Using
Dim sortedScores As List(Of String) = scores.
    OrderBy(Of Integer)(Function(arg) Integer.Parse(arg.Split(splitString).Last())).
    ToList()
```

EDIT: As was suggested in a comment to your answer, XML might be a better option because it frees you from worrying about text format of your data. Using a file that consists entirely of this XML:

```xml
<scores>
  <score Name="Clyde" Moves="32"/>
  <score Name="Above Law" Moves="19"/>
  <score Name="Billy Bob" Moves="19"/>
  <score Name="Pythagoras" Moves="50"/>
  <score Name="Peter Pan" Moves="29"/>
</scores>
```

Read the XML file (I named it `scores.xml` and put it in `C:\`) and get the name and score out of each `score` node. This code prints everything to the console in your original format, but you can do what you wish with it.

```vb
Dim xDoc As XDocument
Try
    xDoc = XDocument.Load("C:\scores.xml")
    Dim scores = From x In xDoc.Descendants("score")
                 Select New With {.Name = x.Attribute("Name"),
                                  .Moves = x.Attribute("Moves")}
    ' you need to tell OrderBy that you will sort by integer, and parse .Moves, 
    ' otherwise compiler doesn't know how to compare anonymous type .Moves
    Dim sortedScores = scores.
        OrderBy(Of Integer)(Function(arg) Integer.Parse(arg.Moves))
    For Each s In sortedScores
        Console.WriteLine("{0}...................Total Moves made: {1:0}", s.Name, s.Moves)
    Next
Catch ex As Exception
    Console.WriteLine("There was an exception: ", ex.Message)
Finally
    xDoc = Nothing
End Try
```